# SQL Error while connecting with SQL server Authentication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

While I am trying to connect to SQL Server using SQL server Authentication ,  I am getting the following error.

**A Connection was established with server but then error occurred during the login process**

[image]
As I browsed through , I got the following steps:

1. In start menu, go to sql server 2005/ Configuration tools/ Surface
   area configuration
2. Select Surface area configurations and connections Remote Connections
3. On the right see named pipes is selected or not. You can go for
           either named pipes only or named pipes and TCP/IP.

I did select Both TCP/IP and Named Pipes and then restarted the SQL Server. But still I am getting the same error.

I checked the SQL error log and it has following message:

> 2012-05-24 17:42:50.27 Server      The Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS   DTC) service could not be contacted.
>   If you would like distributed transaction functionality, please start this service.
>   2012-05-24 17:42:50.27 Server      Database Mirroring Transport is disabled in the endpoint configuration.
>   2012-05-24 17:42:50.29 spid4s      Starting up database 'master'.
>   2012-05-24 17:42:50.45 spid4s      Recovery is writing a checkpoint in database 'master' (1). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
>   2012-05-24 17:42:50.46 spid4s      SQL Trace ID 1 was started by login "sa".
>   2012-05-24 17:42:50.51 spid4s      Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'.
>   2012-05-24 17:42:50.62 spid9s      Starting up database 'model'.
>   2012-05-24 17:42:50.72 spid9s      Clearing tempdb database.
>   2012-05-24 17:42:50.91 spid9s      Starting up database 'tempdb'.
>   2012-05-24 17:42:50.97 spid12s     The Service Broker protocol transport is disabled or not configured.
>   2012-05-24 17:42:50.97 spid12s     The Database Mirroring protocol transport is disabled or not configured.
>   2012-05-24 17:42:50.99 spid12s     Service Broker manager has started.
>   2012-05-24 17:42:57.23 Server      The server could not load the certificate it needs to initiate an SSL connection. It returned the following error: 0x8009030d. Check certificates to make sure they are valid.
>   2012-05-24 17:42:57.26 Server      Error: 17190, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>   2012-05-24 17:42:57.26 Server      FallBack certificate initialization failed with error code: 1.
>   2012-05-24 17:42:57.26 Server      Warning:Encryption is not available, could not find a valid certificate to load.
>   2012-05-24 17:42:57.26 Server      Server is listening on [ 'any'  2036].
>   2012-05-24 17:42:57.26 Server      Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \.\pipe\SQLLocal\SQLEXPRESS ].
>   2012-05-24 17:42:57.26 Server      Server named pipe provider is ready to accept connection on [ \.\pipe\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS\sql\query ].
>   2012-05-24 17:42:57.26 Server      Server is listening on [ 127.0.0.1  3051].
>   2012-05-24 17:42:57.26 Server      Dedicated admin connection support was established for listening locally on port 3051.
>   2012-05-24 17:42:57.28 Server      SQL Server is now ready for client connections. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
>   2012-05-24 17:42:57.29 spid4s      Starting up database 'msdb'.
>   2012-05-24 17:42:57.37 spid4s      Recovery is complete. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
>   2012-05-24 17:43:08.42 Logon       Error: 18452, Severity: 14, State: 1.
>   2012-05-24 17:43:08.42 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection. [CLIENT: ]
>   2012-05-24 17:43:19.27 Logon       Error: 18452, Severity: 14, State: 1.
>   2012-05-24 17:43:19.27 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection. [CLIENT: ]
>   2012-05-24 17:50:25.63 Logon       Error: 18452, Severity: 14, State: 1.
>   2012-05-24 17:50:25.63 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection. [CLIENT: ]
>   2012-05-24 17:50:35.72 Logon       Error: 18452, Severity: 14, State: 1.
>   2012-05-24 17:50:35.72 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection. [CLIENT: ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have to enable sql authentication.
Start the management studio and connect to your database.
Right click porperties and in the security tab, allow sql authentication in addition.
Then you can connect with the user sa. Atm it looks only on windows accounts.